# VSS to TFS migration question\clarification

Tags: version-control, tfs, migration, visual-sourcesafe

> "Team Foundation source control does
> not support sharing, therefore, the
> converter cannot migrate the share
> links between shared files. You may
> have to reorganize files that are
> shared files across projects. During
> migration, shared files are migrated
> by creating a version in the
> destination folder by using the same
> content as the version of the file at
> the time when you started sharing.
> From then onwards, the changes that
> were made to the shared file are
> replicated to both locations."
>
> Quotation taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400771(VS.80).aspx

Does the above statement mean that if i have a shared file shared in 3 different VSS projects, when the migration is complete, there will be four individaul files all at the latest version?

Thanks
Ant

Comment: That is exactly what that means.

Comment: Good news. It didnt make sense that it could be otherwise but "same content as the version of the file at the time when you started sharing" prompted me to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there will be four individaul files all at the latest version?

Yes.

Sharing as VSS allows is, but current practice, regarded as a dangerous approach: to confirm that a change works in all shared cases one needs to checkin and get. But that means a potentially erroneous update has been placed into version control.

Good practice: replace sharing with files with a single file that each use references directly or indirectly (eg. via a shared library).